# Is there a way to determine which class is extending the current module?

Tags: ruby

Say I have this class:

```
#outter.rb
class OutterClass
   extend MyModule

   def self.foo
       puts foo
   end
end
```

Then

```
#mymodule.rb
module MyModule
  class InnerClass
     def self.foo
        OutterClass.foo  #????? This is the question. How to access OutterClass class?
     end
  end
end
```

In the inner class, I want to call the extender class' method. How to determine which class is extending the module?

Comment: This doesn’t make much sense: arbitrary singleton methods (e.g. `MyModule::InnerClass.foo` are not used when extending into another module, and `MyModule::InnerClass` is never used here.

Comment: The question isn't clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code, slightly changed:

```
module MyModule
  def my_method() puts "cat" end
  class InnerClass
    def goo
      foo
    end
  end
end

class OuterClass
  def self.foo
    puts "foo-foo"
  end
end

OuterClass.extend MyModule

OuterClass.my_method # => "cat"
OuterClass.goo       # => undefined local variable or method goo
```

I added my_method() to MyModule to illustrate that my_method becomes a class method of OuterClass after the latter has been extended to include the methods of MyModule.

None of the (class or instance) methods of InnerClass (here just foo) are touched by extend.  As @Andrew explained, InnerClass is just passed over.  Note that `OuterClass.goo` raises an exception, because Ruby cannot find goo.

I pulled `OuterClass.extend MyModule` out of OuterClass to emphasize that extend associates the methods in MyModule with a particular object, here OuterClass.  (You could leave `extend MyModule` in the class definition.)  We could instead (or also) extend an instance of OuterClass:

```
outer = OuterClass.new
outer.extend MyModule
outer.my_method #=> "cat"
```

If you want goo() to have access to foo(), you need to change InnerClass to a module ("InnerModule").  Then you could include it in MyModule:

```
module MyModule
  module InnerModule
    def goo
      foo
    end
  end
  include InnerModule
end

class OuterClass
  extend MyModule
  def self.foo
    puts "foo-foo"
  end
end

OuterClass.goo # => "foo-foo"
```

or add:

```
extend MyModule::InnerModule
```

to OuterClass.  This following also works, but would be more appropriate in other situations:

```
module MyModule
  def self.extended(mod)
    mod.send(:extend, InnerModule)
  end
  module InnerModule
    def goo
      foo
    end
  end
end
```

This uses the [Module#extended](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-extended) hook.